# C++ store a modified MySQL timestamp as string

Tags: c++, mysql, time, connector

I am currently trying to get a `DATETIME` key value from a MySQL database and save it as a string.

However I dont want the time to be in the usual MySQL format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` but rather in a 12 hour format like this: `HH:MM:SS AM/PM`

I already figured out how to "convert" the time format in the MySQL database to my desired format by using this:

```
sql::ResultSet* time = database->Query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`lastLogin`, '%r') FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='%i', id);
```

the MySQL command is valid and the Query returns the right time format (I tested it directly in MySQL).

Now I want to store the result in a char* array but for some reason he always crashes with a SQL Invalid Command Exception when I try to copy the result in to the array.

```
time->first();
char* lastLogin = new char[50];

//here are the variants of the commands I tried, every one crashed:
strcpy(lastLogin, time->getString("lastLogin").c_str());
strcpy(lastLogin, time->getString("DATE_FORMAT(`lastLogin`, '%r')").c_str());
strcpy(lastLogin, time->getString("DATE_FORMAT(lastLogin, '%r')").c_str());
strcpy(lastLogin, time->getString(0).c_str());
```

does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Or is this even possible with MySQL Connector C++?

Comment: What does your `gdb` debugger tell you? Did you try a query like `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`lastLogin`, '%r') AS lastloginr FROM users WHERE user_id='%i'` ?

Comment: yes I already figured out the solution. I had to pass the %r as a string to the method call though, otherwise it would have been interpreted as a simple "r".

Comment: Or perhaps `%%r` since the usual convention is that a double `%` is "expanded" to a single one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try naming the expression in your SQL, giving it an alias:

```
"SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`lastLogin`, '%r') as last_login_str FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='%i'"
```

Then use `"last_login_str"` to retrieve the value.

Comment: I am not sure that this is going to work, so  let me know if it crashes, and I'll remove the answer.

Comment: well in pure MySQL it works. when I run it in C++ its also accepted but the value I get is strange, the char array lastLogin only contains a "r" afterwards.

Comment: It looks like MySQL connect tries to interpret `%r` as a parameter passed to the command. I do not know how to escape `%`, but if you pass `"%r"` string as a parameter to the command, it should work. `database->Query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`lastLogin`, %r) as last_login_str FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='%i'", "%r", id)`. Note that I removed single quotes around `%r`.

Comment: thanks, that worked! btw instead of the alias I could have also used strcpy(lastLogin, time->getString(1).c_str());, so 0 was a wrong parameter