# simplest way to get DATETIME stamp in C++

Tags: c++, sql, datetime

I have an SQL table with DATETIME field in it. I am using the table from C++. when I fill the row, I need to submit a date time. What is the simplest way to get this?

Using ubuntu and need it to work with Qt also, so better without adding external libraries like boost::.

Comment: I am using MySQL, I read and the time format needs to be"The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format."

Comment: See my answer. If it turns out that your SQL library doesn't have one, you can use my DateTime class that I posted on pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation once, so I wrote my own `DateTime` class.

On pastebin:

[DateTime.h](http://pastebin.com/erAXnvG8)

[DateTime.cpp](http://pastebin.com/tthi6J5x)

---

If you are using [`MySQL Connector/C++`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-cpp.html), then I believe this library tries to emulate [`JDBC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) from Java. The classes from the `java.sql` package in Java are defined in the `sql` namespace in C++.

JDBC has a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class, so the C++ library should have a `sql::Timestamp` class.

However, the MySQL 5.6 documentation shows that there are [feature requests for MySQL Connector/C++](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-requests.html) for them to add the `Date`, `Time` and `Timestamp` types from `JDBC` to the C++ library. So they may not be available yet.

For now, [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045030/c-store-a-modified-mysql-timestamp-as-string) suggest that you should use `std::string` for fetching and setting `Timestamp` fields.

Insert:

```
std::string ts_field = "2012/10/26 07:15:00";

pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO date_table(date_field) VALUES (?)");

pstmt->setString(1, ts_field);
pstmt->execute();

delete pstmt;
```

Select:

```
pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT date_field FROM date_table");
res = pstmt->executeQuery();

while (res->next()) 
{
    std::string ts_field = res->getString("date_field");
    cout << ts_field << endl;
}

delete res;
delete pstmt;
```

If you wanted to manipulate these `Timestamp`s in your program. It would be trivial to use these `std::string` objects to create `DateTime` objects using the class that I attached on `pastebin`.

---

If you aren't too deep into `MySQL Connector/C++`, you could consider switching to [`MySQL++`](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/).  This library definitely has a [`DateTime`](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1DateTime.html) type.